# scientext error that i cant find in my code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have a function in data access `tire` that is called by business `tire` and that is called by presentation `tire`.  i think i have written the code correctly and reviewed many times but cannot find the error. Here is my code:

```
public void insertdataintoproducttable(string prname, string prpricpe, string prdescription, string catogory, string image1url, string image2url, string image3url)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqladpter = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into Product_Table(prname,prprice,prdescription,catogory,image1url,image2url,image3url) values('" + prname + "','" + prpricpe + "','" + prdescription + "',''"+catogory+",'" + image1url + "','" + image2url + "','" + image3url + "')", sqlcon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    sqladpter.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `SqlDataAdapter`.  Read the documentation and use `SqlCommand`.

Comment: SLaks   sir can u please reveal this to me how to undestand.

Comment: OP, please choose a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.  Besides illustrating how to execute a SQL Command using ADO.NET, it illustrates some things you must do to protect your system from SQL injection attacks, as well as a number of things that are considered good practice for modern C# programs.

This code is not complete.  You should probably be using an error handler to catch errors that may occur and handle them appropriately.

```
// Declare the function.  
// As a good practice, use Pascal-casing for function/method names.
// As a good practice, use camel-casing for parameter names.
// Instead of passing in a SQL connection, pass a SQL connection string so that the connection 
// can be opened and closed quickly.
// This also takes advantage of connection pooling.
public void InsertDataIntoProductTable(string prName, string prPrice, string prDescription, string category, string image1Url, string image2Url, string image3Url, string connectionString)
{
    // Construct a parameterized SQL INSERT query.
    // Parameterized queries MUST be used to protect our systems from SQL injection attacks.
    // Use string construction so that the query is readable.
    string query = "INSERT Product_Table( " +
                           "prname" + 
                           ",prprice" + 
                           ",prdescription" + 
                           ",category" + 
                           ",image1url" + 
                           ",image2url" + 
                           ",image3url" +
                   ") values(" +
                           "@prname" + 
                           ",@prprice" + 
                           ",@prdescription" + 
                           ",@category" + 
                           ",@image1url" + 
                           ",@image2url" + 
                           ",@image3url" +
                   ")";
    // Create a SqlConnection object.
    // Use a using statement to insure that the SqlConnection object is closed and disposed off when finished.
    using(conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create a SqlCommand object to execute the query.
        // Use a using statement to insure that the SqlCommand object is disposed when finished
        using(cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            // Add parameters and their values to the SqlCommand object
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@prname, prName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@prprice, prPrice);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@prdescription, prDescription);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@catogory, category);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@image1url, image1Url);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@image2url, image2Url);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@image3url, image3Url);

            // Open the database connection
            conn.Open();

            // Execute the SqlCommand.
            // Save the count of records inserted, if of interest to you.
            int recordAffectedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```